# Why regexp with getting block oftext get also line before?

Tags: php, regex

lines with content   :

> Text before
>
> ```
> // SHOW_DONE_BLOCK_START
> /**
>  *
>  * Some Content
>  *
>  
>     
> }
> // SHOW_DONE_BLOCK_END
> ```
>
> TEXT AFTER

and expression :

```
'~[\s]+\/\/[\s]*SHOW_DONE_BLOCK_.*~i'
```

and cut these lines, not leaving empty spaces

I made a fiddle :   https://regex101.com/r/ncmMka/3

Looks like regexp is coreect, but it also gets empty lines BEFORE blocks and that is not what I need.

Adding key “U” - ungready - did not help. How to make it ?

**PHP SIDE CODE :**
In php code having in $contents multiline data with structure I show at the top of the topic with regex :

```
   $contents = preg_replace('~[^\S\n]*\/\/[\s]*SHOW_DONE_BLOCK_.*~i', '', $contents);
```

These blockes with // SHOW_DONE_BLOCK_START are cut, but I still have empty lines left. I need to remove them.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include relevant code in the post itself. You can keep the external link as a reference but the post must be understandable without clicking on it

Comment: The `[\s]+\/\/` will get all whitespaces before and including the `//` (which also means newline characters).

Comment: @apokryfos, how this can be fixed ?

Comment: Instead of using a single regular expression to match the whole file, it seems much easier just to go through the file line by line and remove the lines you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\s` matches a newline too. You can match a whitespace that is not a newline with a negated character set of `[^\S\n]` instead:

```
[^\S\n]*\/\/\s*SHOW_DONE_BLOCK_.*\n
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ncmMka/6

Comment: blhsing, looks like it works , but I still have empty line. I need to remove it too when I use it in preg_replace function

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by an empty line by updating your question with a clear example of an input and an expected output.

Comment: Please read PHP SIDE CODE. Is my question clear now ?

Comment: If you mean to remove the entire matching line you would then need to explicitly include the newline at the end. I've updated the answer accordingly then.

Comment: Yes, looks like it works, but could you please a) Explain your changes - it seems too complicated b) how did you switch to "Substitution" mode ?

Comment: All I did was to add a `\n` in the end to include a trailing newline in the match, which I don't think is complicated. Please clarify specifically what you find complicated. To switch to the substitution mode in regex101.com, click on the word "Substitution" in the left panel.